# can't check username and email and password using UserCreationForm - Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

when i add style to `UserCreationForm in forms.py` and pass it to signup html page and test it , it don't work fine i mean it don't check username and email  if it exist or not and password don't check if it good or no

singup.html :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
  <fieldset class="control-group">
     <label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
      <div class="controls">
          {{ field }}
          <p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }} </p>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" style="background-color:#7952b3" value=" sign up ">
</form>
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Sign Up Form
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True,label=' First Name : ',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}) )
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True,label=' Last Name : ',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}) )
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label=' Email ',widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control center container','style': 'width:85%;text-align: center;background-color:#f6f6f6'}) )

    # constructor of the UserForm, not Meta
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':' add username ','style': 'font-size:19px;text-align: center;'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':' enter pass ','style': 'font-size:19px;text-align: center;'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':' re-type pass ','style': 'font-size:19px;text-align: center;'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            ]
```

how i can fix check username and email and password

Comment: Have you considered using `django-crispy-forms` package for styling? If you use `django-crispy-forms`, you probably wouldn't have to add so many codes manually in `forms.py` or the template, and the built-in django logic for authentication verification may work better.

Comment: Do you get an error? Or is it simply that the page simply appears to reload?

Comment: no i don't use django-crispy-forms

Comment: no i don't get .. i can fill out my signup form and redirect me to login page but the problem is the data that i fill it in form don't go to db and i have problem with form i can't check email and password and username if they stored in my db or no

Comment: @KokHyvv Please add your view to the question.

Comment: thanks everyone i fixed my code

Answer (score 0):

i have edit my code to this and work fine

```
# Sign Up Form
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True,label=' First Name : ',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}) )
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True,label=' Last Name : ',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}) )
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label=' Email ',widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control center container','style': 'width:85%;text-align: center;background-color:#f6f6f6'}) )

    # constructor of the UserForm, not Meta
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':' add username ','style': 'font-size:19px;text-align: center;'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':' enter pass ','style': 'font-size:19px;text-align: center;'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control','placeholder':' re-type pass ','style': 'font-size:19px;text-align: center;'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            ]
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count():          raise forms.ValidationError('Email is already in use, please check the email or use another email')
        return email
```

html signup.html :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
    <br><br>
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
</form>
```